# How to wait for animation finished in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need to append 10 divs with animation of them increase. I need them to appear one after another. I have this code

```
$('#bluebutton').click(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var t = $('<div/>')
    t.css('background-color', 'blue');
    t.css('float', 'left');
    t.css('border', '1px solid white');
    t.appendTo(gallery);      

    t.animate({
      width: 100,
      height: 100
    }, 400, function() {
      // Animation complete.
    });
  }
});
```

but all 10 divs are appending together. Updated: added complete callback.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options - `complete` property

Comment: complete callback isn't working!

Comment: It is working. Maybe you don't know how to properly use it. Update your code so we can see how you are doing it with `complete` and can find out the problem.

Comment: Actually, I recently had problems with using the complete callback.  It was breaking the animation or firing too early, so I think there may be a bug.  I fixed it by using `.animate().promise().done(function() { });`

Comment: Remove the loop, and use the animate complete function to call the next element to be animated

Comment: Archer, not worked for me. Can you provide example?

Comment: The problem here isn't the animate.  You need a delay before it happens and the way you're adding everything and animating at the same time will not give that.  The answers below will do what you need.

Comment: @Archer: No, [`select` isn't broken](http://pragmatictips.com/26). Perhaps there was a misunderstanding in using it (for instance: it fires for *each* animated element, not once for all of the elements in the set).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, in this instance the question of the animate callback is moot until he puts the whole thing in a function as you  and Magicprog.fr both did.  I shouldn't have mentioned the issue I had with the animate callback as it wasn't relevant to the actual problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the completion callback for that:

```js
var gallery = $("#gallery");
$('#bluebutton').click(function() {
  var i = 0;

  addDiv();

  function addDiv() {
    var t = $('<div/>')
    t.css('background-color', 'blue');
    t.css('float', 'left');
    t.css('border', '1px solid white');
    t.appendTo(gallery);      
    ++i;
    t.animate({
      width: 100,
      height: 100
    }, 400, i < 10 ? addDiv : $.noop);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="bluebutton" value="Click me" type="button">
<div id="gallery"></div>
```

Note that bit at the end: `i < 10 ? addDiv : $.noop`. `$.noop` is a function jQuery provides that does nothing, so what that does is say: "If `i` is less than 10, call `addDiv` when the animation is complete."

Comment: Just a question - I'm curious why you used `++i` and not `i++`.  I know they have the same effect unless you're bothered about the return value, but I've never seen anyone use it.  I can only assume it's just personal preference, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Archer: Because English is my first language, and English tends to be verb-first, e.g.: "Increment `i`" makes sense to me, "`i` increment" does not. (I'm surprised you haven't seen it before, I certainly have. But I do see `i++` more.)

Comment: @Archer : that doesn't change anything here. Here is an example :
int i =0;
int a=i++//a=1 et i=0
////////////////
int i =0;
int a=++i//a=1 et i=1

Comment: @Magicprog.fr: Right, I think Archer knows that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, i push "Enter" before writing all my comment, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I think my muscle memory on this makes me type `i++` probably because I knew of `c++` before I knew what `++` actually meant!  Just familiarity and habit.  But no, I've literally never seen anyone use it that way before.  I'd try it myself, but I'm sure I wouldn't be able to sleep tonight if I did :p

Comment: @Archer: No reason for you to change it, except in those cases where it matters. For instance: If I'd done it later when checking `i`, it would matter that I did it my way, but unless it matters, do what feels right! :-)

Comment: No of course.  I'm just torn between being an animal of consistency, and an animal of impulse.  Consistency usually wins though so I'll stick with it.  Thanks for humouring my curiosity :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#bluebutton').click(function() {
  appendBlock(0,10);
});

function appendBlock(number,maxBlocks) {
  if (number <= maxBlocks) {
    var t = $('<div/>')
    t.css('background-color', 'blue');
    t.css('float', 'left');
    t.css('border', '1px solid white');
    t.appendTo(gallery);      
    t.animate({
      width: 100,
      height: 100
    }, 400, function() {
      appendBlock((number+1),maxBlocks);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the others have stated, the animate callback is ideal for what you need, but an alternative is to keep it in a for loop, like you currently have, and simply add a `setTimeout()` to stagger when the new elements are appended...

```
$('#bluebutton').click(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var t = $('<div/>')
            t.css('background-color', 'blue');
            t.css('float', 'left');
            t.css('border', '1px solid white');
            t.appendTo(gallery);      
            t.animate({
                width: 100,
                height: 100
            }, 400);
        }, i * 400);
    }
});
```

Comment: +1, you can also use `t.delay(i * 400).animate(...` rather than `setTimeout`, making it even cleaner.

Comment: Yes, of course.  Even less change to the original code, which is nice :)